# InsertAll & UpdateAll in sqlite-net-pcl VS InsertOrReplaceAll in SQLite.Net-PCL

Tags: c#, xamarin, sqlite.net

I want to remove [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) package and want to use [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) because I later found that `SQLite.Net-PCL` is not officially being maintained.

I have tables which stores `GUID` as primary key of string type in my Xamarin project. I have List of records coming from server and currently using `InsertOrReplaceAll` method to insert new records and update existing one, all at once based on my `GUID` primary key.

Now, `sqlite-net-pcl` does not have `InsertOrReplaceAll` method but instead it has only `InsertAll` & `UpdateAll` methods. [Microsoft msdn Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx) says checking if primary key has value available or not and based on that decide if Records have to be inserted or updated.

But, I have a case where primary key value is always pre-set in the `List`, before insert or update the object and don't want to make a loop to check if record exists or not for more than 500 records.

How to Insert Or Replace all my records at once in this case?

Consider following Example to understand this scenario:

```
using (var conn = new DBConnectionService().GetConnection())
{       
    List<ENTEmployee> employees = new List<ENTEmployee>()
    {
        new ENTEmployee(){ Id = "b977ec04-3bd7-4691-b4eb-ef47ed6796fd", FullName = "AAA BBB", Salary = 15000 },
        new ENTEmployee(){ Id = "c670a3e2-b13f-42b3-849c-fd792ebfd103", FullName = "BBB BBB", Salary = 16000 },
        new ENTEmployee(){ Id = "d961c33c-0244-48dc-8e10-f4f012386eb6", FullName = "CCC BBB", Salary = 17000 },
        new ENTEmployee(){ Id = "35be4508-ff93-4be8-983f-d4908bcc592d", FullName = "DDD BBB", Salary = 18000 },
        new ENTEmployee(){ Id = "0875549c-d06c-4983-b89a-edf81b6aa70d", FullName = "EEE BBB", Salary = 19000 },
    };

    var insertResult = conn.InsertAll(employees);

    //Updated Record
    employees[0].FullName = "AAA Updated";
    employees[0].Salary = 12300;


    //New Records
    employees.Add(new ENTEmployee() { Id = "87f48ecf-715c-4327-9ef3-11712ba4a120", FullName = "FFF BBB", Salary = 20000 });
    employees.Add(new ENTEmployee() { Id = "85f53888-b1e9-460c-8d79-88010f143bcf", FullName = "GGG BBB", Salary = 21000 });

    //Now here, 
    //How to decide which records to be inserted and which records to be updated for List employees?
}
```

Comment: I have requested an issue/feature here : https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented an extension method which is similar to their implementation. You could compere it with the original one in the `SQLite.Net-PCL` [project](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteConnection.cs#L1442).

```cs
static public class SQLiteConnectionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Inserts all specified objects.
    ///     For each insertion, if a UNIQUE
    ///     constraint violation occurs with
    ///     some pre-existing object, this function
    ///     deletes the old object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objects">
    ///     An <see cref="IEnumerable" /> of the objects to insert or replace.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     The total number of rows modified.
    /// </returns>
    static public int InsertOrReplaceAll(this SQLiteConnection connection, IEnumerable objects, bool runInTransaction = true)
    {
        var c = 0;
        if (objects == null)
            return c;

        if (runInTransaction)
        {
            connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                foreach (var r in objects)
                {
                    c += connection.Insert(r, "OR REPLACE", Orm.GetType(r));
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var r in objects)
            {
                c += connection.Insert(r, "OR REPLACE", Orm.GetType(r));
            }
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to Insert Or Replace all my records at once in this case?

There are two ways to resolve the problemL:

1. Traverse your records list and use `conn.InsertOrReplace(object)` for every object in your list:

   for(ENTEmployee emp in employees)
   {
       conn.InsertOrReplace(emp);
   }
2. Use Sql command to insert or replace the records(need your to construct the command string):

   ```
   string cmd = @"insert or replace into employ(id,FullName,salary) 
                 values('c670a3e2-b13f-42b3-849c-fd792ebfd103', 'fullname1',32),
                       ('d961c33c-0244-48dc-8e10-f4f012386eb6', 'fullname2',23);";
   conn.Execute(cmd);
   ```

Comment: Solution 1 is about looping all my records which I don't want to prefer. Consider the case where, there are Thousands or Laks of records. I want to know if I can do all at once without loop. Solution 2 is also not a good one to generate a large string just for a command.

Comment: If you don't prefer these two solutions, then the only solution I can see now is to ask the author of sql-net-pcl to add the function back. You can open an issue in  `sql-net-pcl`'s [github site](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking a moment ago. InsertOrReplaceAll was a very good method in old SQLite.NET PCL, which was doing everything for us for such case.

Answer (score 0):

Just benchmarked 4 different ways to upsert many items :

Context : updating a product (with 7 properties in each object) database with 5000 items.

1. using exists (through a countasync on PK), insertasync and updateasync in a foreach loop : about 30
   seconds
2. using a foreach loop and InsertOrReplaceAsync : about 2 minutes
3. using the extension proposed by @Genfood : about 92ms
4. using the manual query proposed by @Elvis Xia - MSFT : about 81ms

I just made some modifications to the extension to manage the use of async methods

```
public static class SqliteExtensions
{
    static async public Task<int> InsertOrReplaceAll(this SQLiteAsyncConnection connection, IEnumerable objects, bool runInTransaction = true)
    {
        var c = 0;
        if (objects == null)
            return c;

        if (runInTransaction)
        {
            await connection.RunInTransactionAsync(nonAsyncConnection =>
            {
                foreach (var r in objects)
                {
                    c += nonAsyncConnection.Insert(r, "OR REPLACE", Orm.GetType(r));
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var r in objects)
            {
                c += await connection.InsertAsync(r, "OR REPLACE", Orm.GetType(r));
            }
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```