# System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am facing SQLite issue in xamarin forms project. However `SQLiteConnection` I am trying to instantiating in Android platform there getting exception.

Libraries using in android & iOS project

- SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1
- SQLite.Net.Core-PCL 3.1.1

menifest file target versions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
```

AndroidSQLite.cs file

```
using SQLite;
using SQLite.Net;
using System.IO;
namespace XamarinTestList.Droid.Implementations
{
public class AndroidSQLite : ISQLite
{
    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, DatabaseHelper.DbFileName); //DbFileName="Contacts.db"
        var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
        string dpPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");
        var conn= new SQLiteConnection(plat, dpPath);
        return conn;
    }
}
}
```

Getting exception at

```
 var conn= new SQLiteConnection(plat, dpPath);
```

I have installed above libraries on solution level but in *shared project*, there is no option available to install Nuget packages. Shared project screen shot

[image]

Following this article to learn SQLite with xamarin
[xamarin forms-mvvm-sqlite-sample](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2018/03/xamarinforms-mvvm-sqlite-sample-for.html).

Full exception below

> {System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroidInternal.sqlite3_open_v2(byte[],intptr&,int,intptr)
>   at SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLiteApiAndroid.Open
>   (System.Byte[] filename, SQLite.Net.Interop.IDbHandle& db,
>   System.Int32 flags, System.IntPtr zvfs) [0x00000] in
>   <8dbf6ff85082469fb9d4dfaa9eae6b69>:0    at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor (SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform
>   sqlitePlatform, System.String databasePath,
>   SQLite.Net.Interop.SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, System.Boolean
>   storeDateTimeAsTicks, SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer serializer,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tableMappings,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   extraTypeMappings, SQLite.Net.IContractResolver resolver) [0x000a2] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0    at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection..ctor (SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform
>   sqlitePlatform, System.String databasePath, System.Boolean
>   storeDateTimeAsTicks, SQLite.Net.IBlobSerializer serializer,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] tableMappings,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue]
>   extraTypeMappings, SQLite.Net.IContractResolver resolver) [0x00000] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0

Comment: Did you install the NuGet on both your platform and shared code project?

Comment: @Gerald Versluis- Packages I have added across projects(I selected 3 projects including shared project while adding packages). But it doesn't seem there is an option to install packages in shared project. See my updated question where I added screenshot of shared project.

Comment: Have you tried to use sqlite-net-pcl package instead?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I haven't tried that before. But now when I installed that, after changing few namespaces getting error at `SQLite.Net.Platform` Platform is not available.

Comment: Use sqlite-net-pcl package: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net Lib you are using wasn't updated for 2 years.

Comment: @AccessDenied - Thanks, It helped me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) nuget you used is no longer being maintained by it's author. You need to switch to other similar package [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/)

First remove the existing `SQLite.Net-PCL` nuget from all projects and install the one I mentioned above. Remove all old `SQLite` related references from all files.

You need to make some changes in `SQLite` connection related dependency service classes. Then you may adjust some other code which relates to `SQLite`. Resolve the references by adding appropriate using statements for the new nuget package.

I got the same error and I solved it by switching to above nuget package.

**NOTE** : The new nuget package does not have `InsertOrReplaceAll` method yet. So If you have used this method from previous nuget, then for the new nuget, you need to create an [InsertOrReplaceAll extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124476/insertall-updateall-in-sqlite-net-pcl-vs-insertorreplaceall-in-sqlite-net-pcl).

**EDIT**: To get the SQLiteConnection:

```
public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    return new SQLiteConnection(dpPath, false);
}
```

There is no need to pass the platform in this new nuget. Pass `false` if you don't want to store DateTime as Ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Little late but for someone facing the same issue, you just need to add a below line in your native code

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AndroidSQLite))]
```

If this not work then uninstall your existing sqlite-net-pcl and install [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) this library and try again

Comment: Unfortunately not helping this. I am facing same issue.

Comment: Use this [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) nuget it will work

Answer (score 1):

2 choices

1. Change targetSdkVersion < 24, since Android 7, app can not access system private libraries.
2. Add libsqlite.so into your own lib folder.

Comment: @shingo- Can you please tell me where can I get libsqlite.so & where is my lib folder.

Comment: Forget my second option, I think the version of xamarin or the library is too old. take a look [xamarin.android_7.0](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_7/xamarin.android_7.0/)

Comment: @shingo then please remove your 2nd option