# libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so unauthorized access to "/system/lib64/libsqlite.so" Android 8.1

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I'm using SQLite.Net-PCL nugget and when I try to deploy in a Android Device with API Level 24 I get this error `"libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so unauthorized access to "/system/lib64/libsqlite.so"` The thing is that all the solutions  I've found are useless because requires older versions of the Android Targer

Comment: You could refer to: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/503

Comment: You can refer my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052631/system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so-xamarin-forms/52574670#52574670