# Xamarin Forms - System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, interop, system.data.sqlite

I have a project that uses the NuGet package `System.Data.Sqlite` for accessing the DB.

At compile time all works fine, but at runtime when I initialize the connection this error occurs:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll
```

I have tried to install the NuGet package `System.Data.SQLite.Core` but nothing changed.

This error occurs only in Android and iOS device, on UWP all works fine.

How can I solve this?

Anyone has find this error too?

[Here](https://ufile.io/uueqp) a sample project.

Thank you!

**Edit:**

In that post proposed as solution the package used is sqlite-net-pcl, I use a different package, the System.Data.Sqlite.

This is the package that I use:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

**Edit 2:**

I've tried to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/ and works, but I need to test also https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite that doesn't works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so- Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052631/system-dllnotfoundexception-system-lib-libsqlite-so-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Hi, in that post the package used is sqlite-net-pcl, I use a different package, the System.Data.Sqlite.

Comment: You are using this right https://github.com/haf/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: This one https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: Check this https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Answer (score 0):

I solved using Microsoft.Data.SQLite
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite

Comment: Here's a link explaining the difference between: System.Data.SQLite and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (also mentions Mono.Data.Sqlite) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/compare

Comment: Here are some more interesting links about Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.
Interoperability with the native SQLite library (uses SQLitePCLRaw): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/interop

Comment: And that it's used by the EF Core provider for SQLite:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli
SQLite EF Core Database Provider:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli