# Xamarin SQLite Connection With Lock error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) for Xamarin Forms / Xamarin Andriod the previous library [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/) are crashing at run time because its no longer being maintained by it's author [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52574670/1882537) . 
The problem that i'm facing with [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) is when creating `SQLiteConnectionWithLock`

specific with `ISQLitePlatform` parameter

```
new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(ISQLitePlatform, new SQLiteConnectionString(path, true));
```

Parameter `ISQLitePlatform` are interface I tried to implement the interface but I didn't figure out the correct implementation

```
class SQLitePlatform : ISQLitePlatform
    {
        ISQLiteApi ISQLitePlatform.SQLiteApi => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        IStopwatchFactory ISQLitePlatform.StopwatchFactory => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        IReflectionService ISQLitePlatform.ReflectionService => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        IVolatileService ISQLitePlatform.VolatileService => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `ISQLitePlatform` anywhere in that pkg's github repo?

Comment: Inside SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform

Comment: I believe that what Jason was saying is that the constructor for this class `SQLiteConnectionWithLock` has only one parameter and it's the `SQLiteConnectionString` at least for the latest version **1.6.292**. `public SQLiteConnectionWithLock (SQLiteConnectionString connectionString);` what version do you have installed? @DevC

Comment: I have version *1.6.292* too maybe I need to clear solution

Comment: Thanks Jason & @Pinedax I just check the packages and I notice their another 
 package named  **SQLite.Net.Async-PCL** I removed it and its works.

Comment: Could you please put the answer below, so we can resolve the question and its easily searchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the Packages i had in my solution and delete everything related to this package [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL/)

Included:

1- [SQLite.Net.Async-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/) 
2 -[SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN/) 
Only keep this package [sqlite-net-pcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) and its works.